# How to use MySQL count(*) with Order by clause and limit?

Tags: mysql

Consider the following table.

```
+-----+--------------+---------------------+
| id  | account_name | date_time           |
+-----+--------------+---------------------+
| 123 | John         | 2017-07-01 12:12:12 |
+-----+--------------+---------------------+
| 124 | Henry        | 2017-07-02 12:12:12 |
+-----+--------------+---------------------+
| 126 | Vlad         | 2017-07-03 12:12:12 |
+-----+--------------+---------------------+
```

Here if I do the following query,

`SELECT id FROM table_name order by date_time desc limit 0,1;`

I get the output (Which is perfectly fine)

```
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 126 |
+-----+
```

Now, if i execute the query,

`SELECT count(*), id FROM table_name ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 0,1;`

I get the output

```
+-------+-----+
| count | id  |
+-------+-----+
| 3     | 123 |
+-------+-----+
```

Notice that on selecting `count(*)`, the query does not consider the `order`. What is the issue here?
I want the following response.

```
+-------+-----+
| count | id  |
+-------+-----+
| 3     | 126 |
+-------+-----+
```

Comment: MySQL picks 126 arbitrarily (not even randomly). That query is not useful.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I see. So, how can we get the required result then?

Comment: I don't think you really explained the logic behind the required result (spec by example has its limits). Do you want the total row count and the ID that corresponds to largest date, in the same row? Is `date_time` a unique index?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I want the total count with a few conditions (say `where status = 1`). But I want the latest entry (thus order by date_time desc) and No, date_time is not unique. Two ids can have the same `date_time`, in which case we can order by id, i.e., `order by date_time desc, id desc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Let's try on below statement:**

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table_name`) 'Count', id
  FROM `table_name`
  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1;
```

Comment: I think this will work, let me try. But, do you know why it's not working with a simple `select count(*), id`?

Comment: either you use count(*) alone or use count(*), id + "group by"

Comment: if I use group by, it will give count of each group, not the full count.

Comment: Your solution did work, but I still want to know why this happens with `count(*)`

Comment: @ParthapratimNeog I didn't know my explanation about that wasn't clear. Since you don't have a `GROUP BY` clause there isn't enough information to determine which `id` to pick. All other database engines (Oracle, SQL Server, whatever) will just throw an error. MySQL, on the other hand, will behave depending on its settings (and default setting in earlier version is "pick an arbitrary row and go along").

Answer (score 1):

you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT count(*), max(id) AS id
FROM table_name
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0,1;
```

Comment: Wait, I have to update the question. This will work with the current question with the sample table, but, what is the order by is on a `datetime` field? In that case will `max(date_time_column_name)` work?

Comment: I believe we can put the `max(date_time)` in the where clause, but then again, if there are multiple records with the same date_time, it won't help.

Comment: Yes, you should use this answer with the "SELECT count(*), max(date_time)"

Comment: @nacho, max(date_time) is not meaning it's the last row